# Save markers in google maps to SQLite database and load them

Tags: android, android-sqlite, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want save markers in Google map v2 to SQLite database and load them each time come back and run again

this is my code:

```
public class MapReminderActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    Context             context       = this;
    private GoogleMap   map;
    MarkerDataSource    Mdata;
    MyMarkerObj         Mobj;
    final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    boolean             dbCheckedOpen = false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        Mdata = new MarkerDataSource(context);
        Mobj = new MyMarkerObj();

        try {
            Mdata.open();
            dbCheckedOpen = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }

        Cursor cursor = Mdata.db.query(LocationsDB.DATABASE_TABLE, Mdata.cols, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {

            List<MyMarkerObj> mmo = Mdata.getMarkers();
            for (int i = 0; i < mmo.size(); i++)
            {
                String latidutes = mmo.get(i).getLat().toString();
                String langidutes = mmo.get(i).getLng().toString();
                LatLng latlngs = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latidutes), Double.valueOf(langidutes));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(mmo.get(i).getTitle().toString())
                        .position(latlngs));
            }//for
        }//if



        testDialog();

    }//onCreate


    public void testDialog()
    {
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {

                if (dbCheckedOpen == false)
                {
                    try {
                        Mdata.open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                Mobj.setLat(String.valueOf(point.latitude));
                Mobj.setLng(String.valueOf(point.longitude));
                final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(Mobj.getLat()), Double.valueOf(Mobj.getLng()));

                final Dialog reminderdialog = new Dialog(MapReminderActivity.this);
                reminderdialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                reminderdialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_reminder);
                Button btnNextt = (Button) reminderdialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                final EditText edtTitle = (EditText) reminderdialog.findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);


                // Setting latitude in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, Mobj.getLat());

                // Setting longitude in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, Mobj.getLng());


                reminderdialog.show();

                btnNextt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Mdata.addMarker();
                        Mdata.close();
                        dbCheckedOpen = false;
                        reminderdialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }); //setOnclicklistener

            }//onMapLongClick    

        }); //setOnMapLongClickListener

    }//reminderDialog
}
```

this is LocationsDB class :

```
public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /** Database name */
    private static final String DBNAME            = "markerlocations.db";

    /** Version number of the database */
    private static final int    VERSION           = 1;

    /** Field 1 of the table locations, which is the primary key */
    public static final String  FIELD_ROW_ID      = "_id";

    /** Field 2 of the table locations, stores the latitude */
    public static final String  FIELD_LAT         = "lat";

    /** Field 3 of the table locations, stores the longitude */
    public static final String  FIELD_LNG         = "lng";

    /** A constant, stores the the table name */
    public static final String  DATABASE_TABLE    = "locations";
    public static final String  DB_CREATE         = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                                                          FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                                                          FIELD_LNG + " text , " +
                                                          FIELD_LAT + " text , " +
                                                          " ) ";


    /** Constructor */
    public LocationsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (db == null) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

this is MarkerDataSource class :

```
public class MarkerDataSource {

    LocationsDB         mDB;
    SQLiteDatabase      db;
    final String[]      cols = { LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG };
    MapReminderActivity main;


    public MarkerDataSource(Context C) {

        mDB = new LocationsDB(C);

    }


    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }


    public void addMarker()
    {
        main = new MapReminderActivity();
        db.insert(LocationsDB.DATABASE_TABLE, null, main.contentValues);
    }


    public List<MyMarkerObj> getMarkers() {
        List<MyMarkerObj> markers = new ArrayList<MyMarkerObj>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(LocationsDB.DATABASE_TABLE, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while ( !cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            MyMarkerObj mmo = cursorToMarker(cursor);
            markers.add(mmo);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        return markers;
    }


    private MyMarkerObj cursorToMarker(Cursor cursor) {
        MyMarkerObj mmo = new MyMarkerObj();
        mmo.setLat(cursor.getString(0));
        mmo.setLng(cursor.getString(1));
        return mmo;
    }
}
```

this is MyMarkerObj class :

```
public class MyMarkerObj {

    private Long   id;
    private String lat;
    private String lng;



    public MyMarkerObj() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public MyMarkerObj(Long id, String lat, String lng)
    {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setLat(lat);
        this.setLng(lng);
    }


    public MyMarkerObj(String lat, String lng)
    {
        this.setLat(lat);
        this.setLng(lng);
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }


    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }


    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }


    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

}
```

but show this errors in my Logcat:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO locations(null) VALUES (NULL)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
at com.AminApp.Map_Reminder.MarkerDataSource.addMarker(MarkerDataSource.java:51)
at com.AminApp.Map_Reminder.MapReminderActivity$5$1.onClick(MapReminderActivity.java:282)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am confused!
i don't know where i did mistakes. Please help if i go in a wrong way.

Comment: change final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(); to static final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

Comment: Your `main.contentValues` might also be null. You might want to think about setting the second parameter for your first insert to something other than `null`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html for more info on how `SQLiteDatabase.insert` works.